# ¿Cómo se llama el componente de texto? Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy realizando un proyecto en *Android*, y tengo una pregunta.

Quiero un compenente similar al que usa el aplicativo de Pokemon Go, que me permita ingresar texto y ocultarse cuando no es necesario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: para poder entrar texto EditTextView  y el botón Button, mírate los componentes básicos que ofrece Android studio y después reedita la pregunta que no especificas detalladamente a que te refieres, si uno, en conjunto etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es un componente, en realidad son 2 elementos, un `EditText` y un `Button` colocados horizontalmente, para que de muestren de la forma que deseas deves agregarlos dentro de un contenedor `Linearlayout` con orientación horizontal este es un ejemplo:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText android:hint="Escribe aqui"
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </EditText>
    <Button android:text="Aceptar"
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

De esta forma, obtendrías el "componente" que deseas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para obtener el botón sin borde simplemente añade la propiedad :

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

de esta forma:

```
<Button android:text="Aceptar"
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle">
</Button>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si lo mismo es lo que estaba buscando, pero no se como ponerlo fuera de la pantalla.

Answer (score 2):

Para eso te recomiendo usar un `Dialog` puedes hacer que muestre texto predeterminado o si lo complicas un poco puedes hacer que el usuario edite el propio texto, adjunto [documentación.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Answer (score 1):

Si te refieres al campo de texto que está justo encima del teclado y al lado de 'Aceptar' es un EditText colocado en la parte más baja del Activity y que no se oculta cuando sale el teclado virtual.

Si te refieres a la ventana emergente es un dialog.

Comment: si me refieron al editText, pero como hago que aparezca cuando salga el teclado @Manuel Nicolás

Comment: Puedes darle Visibility=GONE o Visibility=Visible para elegir cuando quieres que aparezca o desaparezca. Pero necesitarás alguna especie de evento para controlar eso.

Comment: y como mido la dimensión del teclado?